# how to remove the current item that has been clicked on in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

i have this situation:

```
<ul class="accept_friends">
    <li>
            <div class="center_image">test1</div>
            <div>
                <a href="" id="addfriend" class="gbutton gleft gadd" title="6">Add</a>
                <a href="" id="denyfriend" class="gbutton gright gdelete" title="6">Deny</a>
            </div>
    </li>
    <li>
            <div class="center_image">test2</div>
            <div>
                <a href="" id="addfriend" class="gbutton gleft gadd" title="4">Add</a>
                <a href="" id="denyfriend" class="gbutton gright gdelete" title="4">Deny</a>
            </div>
     </li>
</ul>​
```

when i click on the `#addfriend` or '#denyfriend' i would like to remove that `li` that contains those buttons.

```
$('#addfriend').on("click", function(){

    //remove the current li

});
```

any ideas how to find that `li`?

thanks

Comment: You can not repeat an id in a single document.  Use a class instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest).  Also you can only have one element with a given id.  You should be using classes for your links, not ids.

```
$('.gadd').on('click', function() {
     $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#addfriend').on("click", function(){

    $(this).closest('li').remove();

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [jquery.closest();](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

To do this:

```
$('#addfriend').on("click", function(){
   $(this).closest("li").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.

```
$('#addfriend').on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```